# Deny access to directory in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to deny access to the directory `/dev` in nginx.

If I edit the main configuration file *C:\nginx-1.18.0\conf\nginx.conf* like this, then it works:

```
....
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location /dev {
            deny all;
        }
        ...
    }
}
...
```

But actually, I want all the configuration in the directory where the PHP application is located, so I want to put all information in a configuration file like this *C:\nginx-1.18.0\html\nginx.conf*.

So my approach was to change the master configuration file *C:\nginx-1.18.0\conf\nginx.conf* like this:

```
....
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        include    ../html/nginx.conf;
        ...
    }
}
...
```

and the local configuration file *C:\nginx-1.18.0\html\nginx.conf* like this:

```
location /dev {
    deny all;
}
```

However, this does not work. I can still access `dev/` .

I have tried all variations I could think of like `/dev`, `dev/`, `dev`, `/html/dev` etc., even the absolute path. Nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional question:** Is it possible to deny access to a directory without changing the master configuration file? Like it is done in Apache's `.htaccess` or the `web.config` by IIS?

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is sufficient to your needs. all requested path containing `dev` will be denied.

```
server {
    location ~* dev {
        deny all
    }
}
```

> Is it possible to deny access to a directory without changing the
>   master configuration file? Like it is done in Apache's .htaccess or
>   the web.config by IIS?

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html#deny could be suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't leave comments because I'm new.

The syntax you are using appears correct

```
location = /dev {
    deny all;
   # access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    return 444;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

When you ask Nginx if its config is correct (nginx -t from the command line) do you get any warnings or errors? Are you certain there are no other configuration settings overriding you, a similar location block allowing access.

My personal experience with Nginx has taught me to keep all restrictions as simple as possible and in one place, for example includes/restrictions.conf and I include that file for each of my server blocks.

I note you are on Windows and perhaps Nginx has some idiosyncrasies whilst running on Windows I'm unaware of.

Again, sorry I can't comment otherwise I would have.